# Need help to fix ComboBox programming error

Tags: java

I'm a kinda newbie actually and just self-studying. I really want to learn how to use JComboBox properly. I have created a simple program but it took me forever to fix it.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SampleButtonKo {
    JComboBox combo;

    public void ComboBox1() {
        String course[] = {
            "PM1", "PM2", "PM3", "PM4"
        };
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mang Inasal Ordering System");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        combo = new JComboBox(course);
        combo.setBackground(Color.gray);
        combo.setForeground(Color.red);
        panel.add(combo);
        frame.add(panel);

        combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
                String str = (String) combo.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.print("You have chosen " + str);
            }
        });
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JComboBox = new JComboBox();
    }
}
```

Comment: is it fixed? if not what is the error/problem?

Comment: it has an error cannot find symbol variable JComboBox(); in the line  JComboBox = new JComboBox();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are obvious few errors in your code, you need to have the `constructor` named exactly as your class with no return type. Second, in your `main` you should create an instance of your class *not* the `JComboBox`

```
public class SampleButtonKo{
  JComboBox combo;

  public SampleButtonKo(){
     // Copy your code from "ComboBox1" here
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
   new SampleButtonKo();
  }
}
```

Comment: Obviously it is **not** a complete code, it is only to show where are the errors

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a name for the variable

Instead of

```
JComboBox = new JComboBox();
```

try

```
JComboBox j = new JComboBox();
          ^
```

But perhaps, as iTech suggests, you want to create an instance of your class.

```
new SampleButtonKo();
```